# Model view and labels are not displayed correctly

Tags: 7, views

I created a model view and labels are not displayed correctly when I export with the module: "Views data export".

Here are the contents of my model `views-view-field--sitemap--views-data-export--field-image.tpl.php` :

```
<?php

$fields["field_image"]->content = '<image:loc>' . $field->original_value . '</image:loc>';

echo $fields["field_image"]->content;
```

the result is :

`&lt;image:loc&gt;http://www.domaine.com/xxx.jpg&lt;/image:loc&gt;`

instead of :

```
<image:loc>http://www.domaine.com/xxx.jpg</image:loc>
```

Comment: What format are you trying to export your data as?  It is likely getting encoded so your content is correct in that format.

Comment: @acrosman is in .xml format

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change the content of your XML to provide structural changes to the XML document. This content is escaped so it doesn't break the XML document.

If the whole goal of theming is set your XML image field to a `image:loc` element, you should just change add a **Label** to your field with it set to "image:loc". This will render the XML document image field as an `image:loc` element.